# SonataMediaBundle and Amazon S3 not working

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sonata-media-bundle

I'm trying to get SonataMediaBundle working with Amazon S3 service, 
I've tried the config as described in the bundle docs, but each time i try to upload a picture, i get this error:

```
cURL resource: Resource id #1014; cURL error: couldn't connect to host (cURL error code 7). See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for an explanation of error codes.
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue because I used the wrong region value. Changed `region: eu-central` to `region: s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` and everything worked for me.